# HTML Input file type using only camera option on Android devices

Tags: android, html, browser, input

The issue is regarding Android device LG G2 with Android version 4.4.2 and the default browser.

I am using the following tag to upload an image from the user device to the server:

```
  {<input type="file" accept="image/*;” />}
```

When clicking on the input I am getting two options: Camera and Document.

Is there a way to show only the camera option ?

Thank you all,
Moshe S.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the capture attribute within the input tag as such: capture="camera" or capture='camera'

Note: This has been tested for HTML5.